# Ros-opencv after few computations cannot see the image

Tags: python, kinect, opencv, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

So i'm trying to detect lines with turtlebot via kinect rgb camera. Everything was working until i added cv2.HoughLinesP() i think it still works but image window comes up as menubar only :) canny and gaussianblur works fine with a bit latency but at least i can see the image

i tried to add rospy.sleep() . im not sure where to go from this point. any suggestions?

thanks

```
def __init__(self):
    rospy.init_node('test_node')
    self.bridge=CvBridge()
    
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.callback)
    
def callback(self,data):
    try:
        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)
        
    cv_image=(255-cv_image)
    
    g_img=cv2.cvtColor(cv_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    g_img=cv2.GaussianBlur(g_img,(5,5),200)
    thresh=cv2.Canny(g_img,5,150,5)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh,2,np.pi/180,100,100,1)
    print lines.shape
    for i in range(0,lines.shape[0]):
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[i]:
            cv2.line(cv_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
        
    cv2.imshow("image",lines)
    cv2.waitKey(3)
    #rospy.sleep(10)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240150/ros-opencv-after-few-computations-cannot-see-the-image/) by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `lines` is a numpy array of x,y coordinates for the lines the hough transform found and not an image. You cannot visualise that using

```
cv2.imshow("image",lines)
```

try

```
cv2.imshow("image",cv_image)
```

which is what you draw the lines on anyway with

```
cv2.line(cv_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
```

EDIT:

Also if you want real-time, you want to add a `queue_size=1` to your subscriber to prevent the lag and get real-time results. Otherwise the image you produce will always be lagging behind the input image.

```
self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.callback, queue_size=1)
```

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) on 2016-07-22**:
thank you , i'll try that and update tomorrow

**Comment by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) on 2016-07-23**:
it works thanks alot

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-07-23**:
You're welcome.